# Percentage question based on voting

Tags: percentages

[image]

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: So the correct answer is 14% but you end up with 8%?

Comment: Please take the time to type your question in as text instead of pasting an image, which is neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that Mondale has 60 supporters and Bush 40. Then 6 supporters changed to Bush and 4 to Mondale. So, now Mondale has 60+4-6=58 supporters and Bush has 40+6-4=42 supporters. You need to find the number of supporters $x$ expressed as a percentage of the total number of voters (100), so that 58 becomes 50 (at par). So, $8$ in $58$ is equal to $x$ in 100. Solve for $x$:
$$x=\frac{8}{58}\cdot100\approx14\%$$

Comment: Right. Couldn't understand the language of the question. Thought that 8 voters from a total of 100 voters should switch.

Comment: However, to be precise, your exercises asks for $8$ as a percentage of the electorate, not as a percentage of the voters of Mondale. So, I think that there is something imprecise.

Comment: Right right....